# Type 'URL' has no subscript members in Swift 3

Tags: url, swift3

I am trying to continue a project that was written in swift 1.2 or 2. The converted code to Swift 3 gave some errors, which most of them I have corrected them, but I cannot figure our the error that I wrote on the Title.
The code is:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
var docs: String = paths![0] as? [String: Any] // Error here
```

Any suggestions, I have checked many similar issues, but non seems to work here.

Answer (score 1):

You called `first`, which grabs the first element in the array. Thus `[0]` syntax is redundant. Either call `first` or use `[0]` to get the first item, but not both.

Either

```
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Or

```
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

---

So, putting this all together, you can do:

```
let fileURL = FileManager.default
    .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    .first!
    .appendingPathComponent("Data/userdata.plist")
```

Or

```
let folderURL = FileManager.default
    .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    .first!
    .appendingPathComponent("Data")

// create the folder if it doesn't exist

let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent("userdata.plist")

// now use the `fileURL` here
```

Comment: But still OP is trying to cast the resulting `URL` to `[String: Any]` and store it in a `String`, does not make any sense.

Comment: Yep, I was addressing the error message. But that cast is also wrong.

Comment: I have tried even without paths[0], but then the error was "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]?' to specified type 'String'"

Comment: Well, that was so damn expected. What is your code supposed to do @ToroLoco - as I already said: it does not make any sense.

Comment: @luk2302 I need to use then 'let docsData = docs.appendingPathComponent("/Data/userdata.plist")'

Comment: Lose that `[String: Any]` syntax. We're dealing with an array of URLs (and discussing alternatives to get the first item from that array) and it has nothing to do with a dictionary (which is what `[String: Any]` is).

Comment: @Rob if I change it to "var docs: String = (paths as? String)!" then I get a warning "Cast from 'URL' to unrelated type 'String' always fails"

Comment: It's not a `String`. The `urls` method returns an array of [`URL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) instances. `first` and `[0]` get the first `URL` instance in that array. Don't use `as?` to cast an object of one type to something that it's not.

Comment: No, this code has never worked in any Swift version.